# Merge 2 data frames with indifferent values in columns in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes like this and I want to merge them a bit differently

```
A <- c("CC1_PH","CC1_PH","CC1_PH","CC2_PH","CC2_PH","CC2_PH")
B <- c ("MEAS_Length","MEAS_Breadth","MEAS_Height","MEAS_Breadth","MEAS_Height","MEAS_Length")    
df1 <- data.frame(A,B)

A <- c("CC1_PH","CC1_PH","CC2_PH","CC2_PH")
B <- c ("*","MEAS_Breadth","*","MEAS_Height")
EmpID <- c(444452,16822,339862,14828)
ManagerID <- c(11499,11499,11669,11669)
df2 <- data.frame(A,B,EmpID,ManagerID)
```

I then merge these 2 dataframes

```
df <- merge(df1,df2,by=c("A","B"),all.x=TRUE)

       A            B EmpID ManagerID
1 CC1_PH MEAS_Breadth 16822     11499
2 CC1_PH  MEAS_Height    NA        NA
3 CC1_PH  MEAS_Length    NA        NA
4 CC2_PH MEAS_Breadth    NA        NA
5 CC2_PH  MEAS_Height 14828     11669
6 CC2_PH  MEAS_Length    NA        NA
```

**My desired output is**

```
       A            B EmpID ManagerID
1 CC1_PH MEAS_Breadth 16822     11499
2 CC1_PH  MEAS_Height 444452    11499
3 CC1_PH  MEAS_Length 444452    11499
4 CC2_PH MEAS_Breadth 339862    11669
5 CC2_PH  MEAS_Height 14828     11669
6 CC2_PH  MEAS_Length 339862    11669
```

I want to replace the NA with the corresponding value for "asterisk". How do I place a condition that when it sees a "asterisk" it returns the corresponding ManagerID and EmpID for the value in column "A"?

Kindly provide some directions on how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create logical indexes based on the occurrence of `*` in the 'B' column of 'df2' ('i1') and the NA values in 'EmpID' of 'df' ('i2').  Loop over the corresponding columns in 'df' and 'df2' (3rd and 4th), we `match` the 'A' column in 'df' and 'df2', using 'i1 and 'i2', replace the values of 'df' columns with corresponding column values in 'df2'.  Assign the output back to the 3rd and 4th column in 'df'.

```
i1 <-  df2$B=='*'
i2 <- is.na(df$EmpID)
df[3:4] <- Map(function(x,y) {x[i2] <- y[i1][match(df$A, 
                    df2$A[i1])][i2]
                      x}, df[3:4], df2[3:4])
df
#       A            B  EmpID ManagerID
#1 CC1_PH MEAS_Breadth  16822     11499
#2 CC1_PH  MEAS_Height 444452     11499
#3 CC1_PH  MEAS_Length 444452     11499
#4 CC2_PH MEAS_Breadth 339862     11669
#5 CC2_PH  MEAS_Height  14828     11669
#6 CC2_PH  MEAS_Length 339862     11669
```

Comment: @steveb Actually `df2` doesn't have any `NA`

Comment: Yeah, it was I who had the issue, my `df` was not defined properly.

Comment: @akrun, Thanks for this but can you check the 4th row?, it shows 11499 and not 11669.

Comment: @Sharath Updated the post.

Comment: Wow. This works beautifully in my large data set too. Nice usage of Map. Thanks a lot @akrun for the explanation as well :-) Very helpful in understanding.